# Maven : Can't find the jar file

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

[Target Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj8hA.png)I was using ANT before but I have switched to Maven so pretty new with it . I have set the packaging to JAR in pom.xml. But my question is where can I find this jar file (location) once the build is passed. Where can I set the location in pom.xml and along with it do I have to add any jar plugins in the pom.
[CMD output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymu9U.png)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tiger</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SampleProject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- //for reportng(guice ,velocity is added) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>

                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <!-- <reporting> <plugins> TestNG-xslt related configuration. <plugin> <groupId>org.reportyng</groupId> 
        <artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId> <version>1.2</version> <configuration> 
        Output directory for the testng xslt report <outputDir>/target/testng-xslt-report</outputDir> 
        <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks> <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testDetailsFilter> 
        <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals> </configuration> </plugin> </plugins> 
        </reporting> -->


</project>
```

Comment: The jar will be inside the `target` folder of your project.

Comment: Sorry but it isn't there

Comment: Could you post your POM then? Also, how did you ran Maven? What was the command?

Comment: I have posted my POM . And I have used mvn clean and then mvn install commands.In addition I am running maven from cmd.

Comment: Well with such a POM, after you ran `mvn clean install`, the generated JAR must be inside the `target` folder at the root of the project. There's no way it can't happen.

Comment: Even though all the tests have been passed but I am not getting the BUILD SUCCESS message in cmd.

Comment: Could you post your output?

Comment: Yes i did , pls check the link CMD output

Comment: Please post the output as text and not as a screenshot. Also, it seems that the build isn't finished.

Comment: It just gets stuck once the tests completed , i never get the BUILD SUCCESS message.

Comment: There is a big problem with one of your test then. You could skip them by running `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true` (but that is not very recommended)

Comment: With the above command you mentioned I got the BUILD SUCCESS as well as got the jar in the target folder but don't know why isn"t it happening the same when I'm running the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys I guess the problem was the Chrome browser , I tried running the same tests with Firefox it ran fine , got the BUILD SUCCESS message and jar as well under the target folder. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This plug-in helps to create jar which i used previously.

```
        <!-- Make this jar executable -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <!-- DO NOT include log4j.properties file in your Jar -->
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                    <mainClass>com.project.app</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

further please go throw below links for further understanding
https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make

[How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Thank You

Comment: Yes, please see maven  document link provided for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is based on the messages `The POM for testng...is not valid` that means either you have selected a wrong version (apart from that the given versions are very old) or you don't have access to either Maven central to download your dependencies or you have a proxy/firewall in there...Apart from that you have started tests which are starting a Chrome browser based on selenium which could take some time having started the browser or maybe have stuck based on other problems...

Comment: Well I have updated all the jars but it didnt solve the problem